# Docker Security Vulnerability on Rails container

Tags: ruby, security, docker, dockerfile

I have created Docker container for my microservices application in development environment.

This is how the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev mysql-client

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 3306

RUN mkdir -p /var/test

COPY .  /var/test

COPY Gemfile Gemfile

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock

WORKDIR /var/test

COPY . ./

RUN gem install bundler

RUN bundle install 

CMD rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Recently during a cyber security scanning, I got report that the ports where my containers are running has the vulnerability as below.

Could anyone explain how to rectify this vulnerability and I am not sure from where is the Apache error coming from.

```
Category    Title
apache  Apache HTTPD: error responses can expose cookies (CVE-2012-0053)
```

Comment: If you using [official ruby build](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) then you should open an issue in [github repo](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby) about this

Comment: [This](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/apache-httpd-cve-2012-0053) appears to suggest a solution to your problem, could be that you just need to apply this update to apache.

Comment: Are you overriding the CMD when running the container? Is it possible that you are deploying the app with Apache?

Comment: That looks like a false positive on the CVE as there is no `httpd` installed. The ruby app might be exhibiting the same behaviour though, ask the company that does the scan what the test was.